# Adjusting ODE model output using a Rogan-Gladen estimator in R

Tags: r, function, ode, solver, adjustment

I have made an ODE model in R using the package deSolve. Currently the output of the model gives me the "observed" prevalence of a disease (i.e. the prevalence not accounting for diagnostic imperfection).

However, I want to adjust the model to output the "true" prevalence, using a simple adjustment formula called the Rogan-Gladen estimator (http://influentialpoints.com/Training/estimating_true_prevalence.htm):

True prevalence = 
(Apparent prev. + (Specificity-1)) / (Specificity + (Sensitivity-1))

As you will see in the code below, I have attempted to adjust only one of the differential equations (diggP).

Running the model without adjustment gives an expected output (a proportion between 0 and 1). However, attempting to adjust the model using the RG-estimator gives a spurious output (a proportion less than 0).

Any advice on what might be going wrong here would be very much appreciated.

```
# Load required packages
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)
library(deSolve)

# Set time (age) for function
time = 1:80

# Defining exponential decay of lambda over age
y1 = 0.003 + (0.15 - 0.003) * exp(-0.05 * time) %>% jitter(10)
df <- data.frame(t = time, y = y1)
fit <- nls(y ~ SSasymp(time, yf, y0, log_alpha), data = df)
fit

# Values of lambda over ages 1-80 years
data <- as.matrix(0.003 + (0.15 - 0.003) * exp(-0.05 * time))

lambda<-as.vector(data[,1])
t<-as.vector(seq(1, 80, by=1))
foi<-cbind(t, lambda)
foi[,1]

# Making lambda varying by time useable in the ODE model
input <- approxfun(x = foi[,1], y = foi[,2], method = "constant", rule = 2)


# Model
ab <- function(time, state, parms) {
  with(as.list(c(state, parms)), {

    # lambda, changing by time
    import<-input(time) 

    # Derivatives

    # RG estimator: 
    #True prevalence = (apparent prev + (sp-1)) / (sp + (se-1))

    diggP<- (((import * iggN) - iggR * iggP) + (sp_igg-1)) / (sp_igg + (se_igg-1))
    diggN<- (-import*iggN) + iggR*iggP

    dtgerpP<- (0.5*import)*tgerpN -tgerpR*tgerpP
    dtgerpN<- (0.5*-import)*tgerpN + tgerpR*tgerpP

    # Return results
    return(list(c(diggP, diggN, dtgerpP, dtgerpN))) 
  })
}

# Initial values
yini  <- c(iggP=0, iggN=1, 
           tgerpP=0, tgerpN=1) 

# Parameters
pars  <- c(iggR = 0, tgerpR = (1/8)/12, 
           se_igg = 0.95, sp_igg = 0.92)

# Solve model
results<- ode(y=yini, times=time, func=ab, parms = pars)

# Plot results
plot(results, xlab="Time (years)", ylab="Proportion")
```

Comment: What is the code line you used before trying the correction? `diggP<-  ...`

Comment: Is it possible to use the correction after the ODE calculation? So use `iggP_real = (results[,"iggP"] + pars["sp_igg"] - 1) /(pars["sp_igg"] + pars["se_igg"] - 1)`.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. Before the code read:

`diggP<- (import * iggN) - iggR * iggP`

Yes that seems to work, thanks! However, preferably I would like to see two outputs from the model: one ODE giving the apparent result and one the corrected result. It does not seem to like it when I put it in the equations though.